# Azure ssl certificate not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

I have configured a SSL certificate in azure, this is how the configuration pages look.

[image]
[image]

But when I navigate to the site I get an 'your connection is not secure' error, looks like no certificate exists.

[image]
[image]

An Chrome on the other hand it looks invalid

[image]

Comment: Do you use a self-signed certificate?

Comment: no, it's a let's encrypt certificate https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: Can you change to the TLS 1.2. `Your app allows TLS 1.0 by default, which is no longer considered secure by industry standards, such as PCI DSS. ` [refer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#enforce-tls-1112)

Comment: I suggest going through this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-does-your-connection-is-not-secure-mean).

Comment: @NancyXiong-MSFT tls 1.2 did not solve the issue

Comment: Can you verify it by using another browser like IE, chrome?

Comment: I did, added a new screenshoot.

Comment: probably dns mismatch

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an Azure issue, its a fault with your cert. Your certificate shows as using the "Fake LE Intermediate X1" intermediate cert. This is usually down to using the let's encrypt test/staging service which does not issue valid trusted certs. Make sure whatever process you are using to generate the cert is using the production LE servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if you have added binding with your custom hostname which should map your SSL certificate DNS name in your Azure Web app service.

[image]

[Tutorial: Map an existing custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)

Comment: Is this helpful?

Comment: No, this is not helpfull, I already verified this and it shows as binded. Thank for the quick reply.

Comment: Does the hostname as binded match the CN name of your certificate?

Comment: Yes it does, I gave up and purchased a certificate for the portal and that worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up purchasing a new certificate from azure and gave up on trying to integrate let's encrypt.